# Check if XML Element has children or not, in ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, children

I retrieve an XML documents this way:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse(urllib2.urlopen(url))
for child in root.findall("item"):
  a1 = child[0].text # ok
  a2 = child[1].text # ok
  a3 = child[2].text # ok
  a4 = child[3].text # BOOM
  # ...
```

The XML looks like this:

```
<item>
  <a1>value1</a1>
  <a2>value2</a2>
  <a3>value3</a3>
  <a4>
    <a11>value222</a11>
    <a22>value22</a22>
  </a4>
</item>
```

How do I check if `a4` (in this particular case, but it might've been any other element) has children?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try the `list` function on the element:

```
>>> xml = """<item>
  <a1>value1</a1>
  <a2>value2</a2>
  <a3>value3</a3>
  <a4>
    <a11>value222</a11>
    <a22>value22</a22>
  </a4>
</item>"""
>>> root = ET.fromstring(xml)
>>> list(root[0])
[]
>>> list(root[3])
[<Element 'a11' at 0x2321e10>, <Element 'a22' at 0x2321e48>]
>>> len(list(root[3]))
2
>>> print "has children" if len(list(root[3])) else "no child"
has children
>>> print "has children" if len(list(root[2])) else "no child"
no child
>>> # Or simpler, without a call to list within len, it also works:
>>> print "has children" if len(root[3]) else "no child"
has children
```

I modified your sample because the `findall` function call on the `item` root did not work (as `findall` will search for direct descendants, and not the current element). If you want to access text of the subchildren afterward in your working program, you could do:

```
for child in root.findall("item"):
  # if there are children, get their text content as well.
  if len(child): 
    for subchild in child:
      subchild.text
  # else just get the current child text.
  else:
    child.text
```

This would be a good fit for a recursive though.

Comment: doesn't work. Could you use my example with iteration?

Comment: it does not work, because your iteration loop yields no elements, since there are no elements named 'item'

Comment: how do I get "<a11>" and "<a22>" elements?

Comment: It works, check this pythonfiddle: http://pythonfiddle.com/check-if-element-has-children-or-not Else tell me exactly what did not work.

Your sample did not work though, hence why I modified it. Let me modify my answer to tell you how to access the subchildren.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way I have been able to find is to use the `bool` value of the element directly. This means you can use `a4` in a conditional statement as-is:

```
a4 = Element('a4')
if a4:
    print('Has kids')
else:
    print('No kids yet')

a4.append(Element('x'))
if a4:
    print('Has kids now')
else:
    print('Still no kids')
```

Running this code will print

```
No kids yet
Has kids now
```

The boolean value of an element does not say anything about `text`, `tail` or attributes. It only indicates the presence or absence of children, which is what the original question was asking.

Comment: Has been deprecated for years due to confusion whether there is an element object or not:  
https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elements-are-lists

Comment: @GringoSuave. Apparently my answer was 8 years out of date even when I wrote it. Just now I'm working on my first project actually using lxml, before that I only read some old docs :)

Answer (score 4):

As of today, using Python 3.9 you can use the `len()` function on an ElementTree
element.

In this case, for example:

```
if len(child[3]) > 0:
    a4 = child[3].text
```

Comment: This is the correct, modern solution.  Does not use deprecated test, or build a list to be thrown away.

Comment: Looks like lxml supports this as well, probably earlier but not sure exactly when.

Answer (score 3):

I would personally recommend that you use an xml parser that fully supports xpath expressions. The [subset supported by `xml.etree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) is insufficient for tasks like this.

For example, in `lxml` I can do:

"give me all children of the children of the `<item>` node":

```
doc.xpath('//item/*/child::*') #equivalent to '//item/*/*', if you're being terse
Out[18]: [<Element a11 at 0x7f60ec1c1348>, <Element a22 at 0x7f60ec1c1888>]
```

or,

"give me all of `<item>`'s children that have no children themselves":

```
doc.xpath('/item/*[count(child::*) = 0]')
Out[20]: 
[<Element a1 at 0x7f60ec1c1588>,
 <Element a2 at 0x7f60ec1c15c8>,
 <Element a3 at 0x7f60ec1c1608>]
```

or,

"give me ALL of the elements that don't have any children":

```
doc.xpath('//*[count(child::*) = 0]')
Out[29]: 
[<Element a1 at 0x7f60ec1c1588>,
 <Element a2 at 0x7f60ec1c15c8>,
 <Element a3 at 0x7f60ec1c1608>,
 <Element a11 at 0x7f60ec1c1348>,
 <Element a22 at 0x7f60ec1c1888>]

# and if I only care about the text from those nodes...
doc.xpath('//*[count(child::*) = 0]/text()')
Out[30]: ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value222', 'value22']
```

Comment: Suggesting lxml assumes there is a problem with performance and xpath features are lacking. It's definitely better than ElementTree but I wouldn't go this way if there is no problem with the latter, especially considering that lxml requires installation and it's not always a nice walk in the park.

Comment: Performance is a thing, yes, but full xpath support means that you do all the work of selecting nodes in one compact place.  xpath queries take me a few seconds to write; writing python code to walk the tree and select the nodes I want takes longer and is far likelier to generate bugs.  There are lots of benefits other than performance.

Answer (score 1):

Update 2022:

The elements are iterable, and also the boolean operation is implemented. So you can directly use it to check whether an element as children like this:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml = """<item>
  <a1>value1</a1>
  <a2>value2</a2>
  <a3>value3</a3>
  <a4>
    <a11>value222</a11>
    <a22>value22</a22>
  </a4>
</item>"""
root = ET.fromstring(xml)

def traverse(e_):
    for c in e_:
        if not c:  # element c has no children
            print(f"text of element: '{c.text}'")
        else:
            traverse(c)

traverse(root)
```

Produces the following output:

```
traverse(root)

text of element: 'value1'
text of element: 'value2'
text of element: 'value3'
text of element: 'value222'
text of element: 'value22'
```

Deprecated solution (Python 2.7, <Python 3.9):

The element class has the get children method. So you should use something like this, to check if there are children and store result in a dictionary by key=tag name:

```
result = {}
for child in root.findall("item"):
   if child.getchildren() == []:
      result[child.tag] = child.text
```

Comment: `getchildren` is deprecated though since version 2.7. [From the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html): Use list(elem) or iteration.

Comment: `getchildren` is not just deprecated. It was removed in Python 3.9.

Comment: You're mentioning *length operation*, but you're not actually using it here, nor explaining how to use it. Can you provide an updated example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iter method

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

etree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = etree.getroot()
a = []
for child in root.iter():
    if child.text:
        if len(child.text.split()) > 0:
            a.append(child.text)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use a very simple method

```
list(<element>)
```

if list is empty then there is no child there.

Comment: Can you explain and also show how to use it on the example from above?